# Firebase rule - Permission Denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase data where the structure of the data is as follows:

```
{
  "users": {
     "123456": {
         "Name": "ABC"
         "uid": "123456"
     }
  }
  "Orders":{
     "987654": {
         "Customer ID": "123456"
         "Other Details":  *****
     }
  }
}
```

Where users are the list of users in my database. And Orders are orders placed by each of the users. The user id and order id shown are dummy. They are generated by push key. Now the orders can be read by the user if the "Customer ID" is same as the userid. For which I have the following Firebase rule:

```
"Orders":{
  ".indexOn": ["Customer ID"],
  "$Orders_id": {
    ".write": "((root.child('Orders/'+$Orders_id+'/Customer ID').val() === auth.uid && auth != null) ||(auth != null && !data.exists())",
    ".read": "root.child('Orders/'+$Orders_id+'/Customer ID').val() === auth.uid && auth != null "
  }
}
```

However, I get the message "Permission Denied". The first write of the data was flawless. Can someone please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure read / write about right node from the coding.
you can access to read/write in this node => `Orders/{Orders_id}`
you can't access to read/write in this node => `Orders`